# POST using cURL different data types

Tags: php, xml, curl, kml

I generate some xml (actually google kml file)

```
$kml = array('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>');
$kml[] = '<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">';
$kml[] = ' <Document>';
```

I make a string of it

```
$kmlOutput = implode("\n", $kml); //Join array elements with a string
```

Then I make an array

```
$data = array('code' => 'somecode', 'xml' => $kmlOutput);
```

Then I send my data of cURL

// Setup cURL

```
$ch = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 8);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

/**
 * Check for some errors (omitted here)
 */
curl_close($ch);
```

Upload.php on another server

```
/* MAIN CODE*/
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ){
    print "\n\n";
    echo "DEBUG: Vardump Post"; 
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo "DEBUG:";
    var_dump($_FILES);

    if ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/xml"  && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < $maxSize) ){
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
            echo "Error: (Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . ")<br />";
        } else {
            echo "Code: ".$_POST['key']. "<br />";
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
            echo "Temp Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]. "<br />"; // temporary copied files disappears when the script ends


            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: " . $dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

However the var_dump($_FILES); and even var_dump($_FILES["code"]); return empty?

-Am I missing something here?
-Can I send two types of data?

Comment: Have you tried a header with multipart/form-data?

Comment: No; and i'm not sure what you mean? How can i set the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get it via `$_FILES` because you are not uploading any file

To upload a file you need to use `@` sign followed by the location of your file

```
 $data = array('code' => 'somecode', 'xml' => "@". $PATH_TO_XML_FILE);
```

You can also Just upload directly like this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $kmlOutput);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/xml"));
```

Example

```
$xml =   __DIR__ ."/Pages.xml"; //full part to XML
$data = array('code' => 'somecode', 'xml' => "@$xml");
$ch = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 8);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output ;
```

On remote Page

```
    var_dump($_POST,$_FILES);
```

Comment: so I have to write the xml to a local file first? is that slower than directly passing it as a string and only parsing it to a file on the server?

Comment: Have Given you the 2 possibilities .. either write to xml file first .. or post directly .. but the first option would give you ability to add other variables

Comment: thx; but by just uploading my var_dump($_FILES); still returns empty

Comment: Which of the code are you using ... put your updated code in paste bin let me see

Comment: You code would not work .. i asked you to chose one not the 2 .... Please read my answer again .... If you are using the first option you should not set `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`

Comment: no i'm using the second option; i think it's going to be faster than writing to a file first. Why would my code not work?(I'm not sending the $data so i don't see why you mean i've used both methods?

Comment: Use the first option since you still want to send `code=comecode` ,, if you are using the second option you would not be able to send additional variable

Comment: okay: but i can still use the curl auth for what i'm trying to accomplish with that variable? Is it really not possible to just send the file like you said?

Comment: You the updated code .... create a smile XML file and just test you would see what am saying ...... a